# Stream image sensor data as video in a Non-Live stream

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

I have image sensor data (in my case in a ROS bag file), that means many single images that I have to stream to a webinterface. The goal is to simply have a video in the browser where I can select the time on the seek bar, that means I don't want a live stream.

Live encoding and streaming with FFmpeg works.

What is the best approach? The total Content-Length is unkown, since it is on-the-fly encoding, so I don't know how to implement `206 Partial Content` where I send a `Content-Range`. Even if this was working, I need to encode valid partial content with FFmpeg.